# Job completed but missed instructions on items they want me to submit

Tags: salary, new-job

I found work through a temp staffing agency. It was my job to promote a specific line of product at a pet store, however the specific instructions were never made clear to me. Essentially I went to the location at the time they told me to and I assumed their would be someone there to meet me. There wasn't and I called my contact and she said speak to the store manager and he should have a box of items I should use and give samples out. I did this and it went well.

Given the timing of events, the day I did this work was very close to when I first heard about it. I made clear to the temp agency that I worked full time (with strange hours) and may not be available immediately to reply to an email from them or a phone call. They said they understood.

I did receive an email just before my shift started and it told me to do additional things that I didn't. The instructions were very confusing, for example it talked about keeping track of my sales - but I was told to give samples away for free so there were no sales? And in part of the completion survey it said to upload the pictures I took. But I received no instructions on anything to do with pictures. Also I was supposed to count the number of products of a certain brand in the store, but I didn't know I was supposed to.

Going forward I'm not sure what to do. I'm suppose to submit a survey with all this information I don't have.  Should I wait and see if I receive pay and if not contact someone to explain what happened? Should I contact the temp agency or the company that hired them (it was their product I was promoting)? I had emailed them a day ago saying I didn't understand what pictures they were referring to that they wanted me to upload but haven't got a response.

While I may not have done the job fully correctly, I certainly did some of it correctly and promoted the product by talking to customers and giving out samples. I hope they don't try giving me no pay because of this.

There were no contracts signed but I sent the temp agency an invoice.

Answer (score 6):

> Going forward I'm not sure what to do.

Ask enough questions so that you understand what you are supposed to do *before* you are expected to do it.

Start with your employer (the agency). Stop assuming things. If you don't understand their emails, call and ask for clarification.

Perhaps this is the type of temp job where you are expected to quickly figure things out on your own. If you aren't able to do that, ask for a different assignment.

> Should I wait and see if I receive pay and if not contact someone to
>   explain what happened? Should I contact the temp agency or the company
>   that hired them (it was their product I was promoting)?

If you are in the US, you are entitled to be paid for the hours you worked even if you did a poor job (unless it was piece/project work).

Comment: +1 for **call and ask for clarification.** When you need to know something quickly, calling is always better than emailing.